# How to receive data on python from android

Tags: android, python, sockets

I am using this method in my android application in order to send data to a python server

```
public void send(String heart_rate, String url) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair>    output;

    HttpResponse    response;
    HttpClient  httpclient;
    HttpPost    httppost;

    // create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost(url + "/sendData");

    output = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {
        // set up the information in the post request
        output.add(new BasicNameValuePair("heart_rate", heart_rate));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(output));

        // execute HTTP post request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // logging 
        Log.d(TAG, "sent the data (rate: " + heart_rate + ", level"  + ")" + "\n with respone:" + 
                response.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }   
}
```

Now the problem is how to receive it in Python.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard about REST?

Comment: No, I am a noob at this stuff.